# How to identify and print string with the delimiters

Tags: string, python-3.7

I'am trying to make a "Quiz Scanner " that uses OCR to scan quizzes online so that I could compile quizzes from sources online myself to be able to answer them offline. I got tired of doing the Copy and paste thing and just use OCR instead.

I have no problems with the OCR part as of the moment.The part that i'am having trouble now is I need to separate the questions from the choices and from the choices the correct and wrong ones. Below is a over simplified code of my attempt in separating them.

I need them to be separated because I want to export it to a spread sheet in excel . Really need your help as always stackoverflow community

```
import re

scannedmcq = 'Insert Question Here @ A(correct) > B > C > D' #Output of my OCR script
# What if this is the new string
# 'Insert Question Here > A > B > C @ D'
# The Delimiter @ Is the correct answer while > is the wrong answer
# How to Identify and print which part of the string has the delimiter @
text = re.split(r'[@>]\s*', line)
# Manually Printing the strings 
print(text[0])
print(text[1])
print(text[2])
print(text[3])
print(text[4])
```

[sample quiz online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZF7z.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try finding the index of `@` character in your string then after two indexes apart is your correct answer.

```
scannedmcq = 'Insert Question Here @ A(correct) > B > C > D'

result = scannedmcq[scannedmcq.index('@')+2]
print("Correct Answer is':", result)
```